# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, symfony, exception, datetime

I configured redmine with my website for handling exceptions. Now when website is on production environment I have strange exception.

StackTrace:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (date) at position 0 (d): The timezone could not be found in the database") in "ToFrontendBundle:Page:cruise-periodic.html.twig" at line 8.

#95: To\FrontendBundle\Controller\PageController->cruisePreviewAction(8, way, date)
#106: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller->render("ToFrontendBundle:Page:cruise-periodic.html.twig", array)
#112: Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->renderResponse("ToFrontendBundle:Page:cruise-periodic.html.twig", array, NULL)
#83: Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine->render("ToFrontendBundle:Page:cruise-periodic.html.twig", array)
#53: Symfony\Bridge\Twig\TwigEngine->render("ToFrontendBundle:Page:cruise-periodic.html.twig", array)
#4423: Twig_Template->render(array)
#4416: Twig_Template->display(array)
#4446: Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(array, array)
```

But, I handle exception like:

```
        try {
            $date = new \DateTime($date);
            $date = $date->format('j-n-Y');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $date = new \DateTime("now");
            $date = $date->format('j-n-Y'); 
            $first = false;
        }
```

My cruise-periodic.html.twig:

```
<span class="padding-left-10 light-green text-14 selected-date" data-date="{{ date | date('j/n/Y') }}">{{ date | toDateFormat }}</span>
```

What I do wrong?

**EDIT**
Someone is causing the exception but i cannot tell how. I cannot manually test this situation. String variables "date" and "way" are replaced in js. Possibly that someone is finding the dom href and invoking it blindly. Could it be robots or bots ? How I can prevent them from accessing this action?

Comment: You are passing the string "date" to DateTime when it expects a parseable date, hence "Failed to parse time string (date)" and cruisePreviewAction(8, way, date). Find out why.

Comment: Try to use 'Y-m-d' format of `$date` for parsing, is it work?

Comment: @Gordon I use var cruise = new Cruise($('#vessal-{{ cruise.id }}'), "{{ path('to_frontend_cruise_preview', {'id': cruise.id, 'way': 'way', 'date': 'date' }) }}"); in JS, but I always replace date and way with form fields. Anyway, I handling exceptions, so I couldnt have this problem, but I have.

Comment: @Victor I can't use this format. Client want format j-n-Y.

Comment: @psalkowski I meant try to use it for testing is it work, for define a problems

Comment: @Victor I cannot test it, because someone is causing the exception but I cannot tell how. And this is not a problem in format date. Someone use url with parameters: "way" and "date", but this parameters should be replaced in JS like way: 0, date: 04-02-2014 and put ajax (post) for reload content. If someone has disabled JS in browser, then page is not visible. Maybe someone browse DOM elements looking for href (like bots / robots)?

Comment: @psalkowski try to execute code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I meant try to execute next code:

```
    try {
        $date = new \DateTime('2010-10-10');
        $date = $date->format('j-n-Y');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $date = new \DateTime("now");
        $date = $date->format('j-n-Y'); 
        $first = false;
    }
```

Is it also catch this exception or it work?

Comment: Аnd what is the result?

Comment: Please wait 20 hours for results

Comment: It's been 6,467 hours - any luck? :>